# ¿Cómo evito que el ultimo elemento de un array tenga coma?

Tags: php

Tengo esta duda hace unos días estaba trabajando con un mapa simple, y me vi en la necesidad de poner el ultimo campo estático. Empero me gustaría saber cómo hacerlo todo dinámico.

Dejo el fragmento de código adelante:

```
var sucursales = [
    {if isset($sucursales)}
        {foreach from=$sucursales item=su}
            ['{$su.comment}', {$su.lat}, {$su.long}, {$su.id}],
        {/foreach}
    {/if}
        ['Sucursal de Plaza las Americas', 18.013836, -92.919293, 5]
    ];
```

Comment: lo pusiste estatico por la coma?

Comment: Sí, es que si lo recibía todo en el arreglo me daba error por que el ultimo elemento tenia coma.

Comment: no soy tan experto en php, pero puedes contar la cantidad de items con anticipacion? y agregar un if, que solo agregue la coma si no llego al final?

Comment: Mira si se puede de esa manera, pero lo que trataba de evitar era usar otro if o ver si se podía de otra forma. Gracias.

Comment: no se puede.. ni en php, ni en ningun lenguaje, salvo que puedas remover caracteres de la estructura una vez finalizado.. cosa que en este caso no parece posible...

Comment: Bueno, de cualquier forma gracias. Tendrá que ser a la antigua.

Comment: dale tiempo.. capaz alguien tiene algun metodo desconocido por nosotros...

Comment: puede generarlo de forma dinámica como un string separando por comas los datos, luego como el ultimo tiene una coma se lo eliminas, rtrim($arraynama,","); y al final combiertes el string en un array separado por coma

Answer (score 0):

La pregunta esta etiquetada como php pero esa sintaxis lleva a confusión, deberías poner un ejemplo simple de lo que quieres, que sea fácil de entender para todo el mundo.

Crear una cadena separada por comas desde un Array

Con PHP

```
$MiArray = array('apellido', 'email', 'teléfono');
$separado_por_comas = implode(",", $MiArray);

echo $separado_por_comas; // apellido,email,teléfono
```

Con JavaScript

```
var MiArray = ["apellido", "email", "teléfono"];
var separado_por_comas = MiArray.join();

alert ( separado_por_comas ); // apellido,email,teléfono
```